# Manufacturer part search in Altium 17

Tags: altium, footprint

Do you know if the "manufacturer part search" is available in Altium 17?
I have tried it in Altium 23 but I am not able to find it in Altium 17.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Manufacturer Part Search panel was [introduced in version 19](https://doc-test.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/new?version=19.0).